# In VB6, is there an autogenerated code for the Validate Event?

Tags: vb6

In VB6, textboxes have their CausesValidation property set to True by default. In this case, is there some autogenerated validation code as well when the Validate Event fires? I suppose that such autogenerated code would check, at a minimum, whether the field is non-empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, no there is no autogenerated validation code associated with the TextBox Validation event.  You'll have to write your own where you can check the contents of a TextBox's Text property, etc.

You might find the following useful:

[The CausesValidation Property and the Validate Event - Visual Basic 6 TextBox Control](http://visualbasic.freetutes.com/learn-vb6/8.3.causevalidation-property-validate-event.html)

If you're wondering how you might verify that a TextBox is 'non-empty' you might use the following validation event example from the link:

```
Private Sub txtRequired_Validate(Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Check that field is not empty.
    If txtRequired.Text = "" Then 
        MsgBox "Please enter something here", vbExclamation
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Your link seemed to have gone wrong somehow. I edited it to go to (I hope) the right place!

Comment: @MarkJ Thanks!  Looked funny when I pasted it in - should have checked it.

Comment: This sort of treatment works fine in small doses, but (as I am sure Jay will agree), if you are doing this with a large number of controls it is better to centralize your validation code by calling a validation procedure from your validate event handlers.  That helps to minimize repetitive code.

Answer (score 0):

it just means that it will call the validate function when you leave the field. You still need to write your validation.  Check this for an example: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/automate-data-validation-in-vb6-with-causesvalidation-and-validate/5904942

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.

`CausesValidation` controls whether `Validate` event is fired for the control. If it is fired, but no handler is defined in your code, nothing happens and validation succeeds.