# Validate user input in a TextBox

Tags: vb6

User provides value in `txtAmount` TextBox that I later process this way:

```
c = txtAmount.Text 'GET AN ERROR HERE BECAUSE I NEED C TO BE AN  INT
```

I want a user to be able to correct entered value, so I can get `c` as an integer:

```
If Not (IsNumeric(txtAmount.Text)) Then
  lblMsg.Caption = " Please enter you answer numericly "
  txtAmount.Text = ""
  txtAmount.SetFocus 'HERE IS WHAT I WANT TO FIX
End If
If (txtAmount.Text = "") Then
  lblMsg.Caption = " Please enter amount to convert"
  txtAmount.SetFocus
End If
```

Where should I place my validation code so its called before I process entered value?

Comment: Take a look at accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047877/in-vb6-is-there-an-autogenerated-code-for-the-validate-event. See if it sheds some light.

Comment: first of all don't rely on implicit conversion, but use val() or cint() to convert the text to an integer ... aside from that, if you only need integers in that textbox, you can limit the input to just numbers so it will always be an integer. You can use the KeyPress event for that

Answer (score 1):

Below is a sample project to show what I mean:

```
'1 form with:
'  1 textbox: name=Text1
Option Explicit

Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
  KeyAscii = NrOnly(KeyAscii)
End Sub

Private Function NrOnly(intKey As Integer) As Integer
  Dim intReturn As Integer
  intReturn = intKey
  Select Case intKey
    Case vbKeyBack        'allow backspace
    Case vbKey0 To vbKey9 'allow numbers 0 to 9
    Case Else             'block all other input
      intReturn = 0
  End Select
  NrOnly = intReturn
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to validate it while typing.
To do it use the change event like this:

```
Private Sub txtAmount_Change()

    On Error GoTo ErrManag

    If txtAmount.Text = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Not ((CInt(txtAmount.Text) >= 0) And (CInt(txtAmount.Text) <= 10)) Then MsgBox " Some max-min-error message"

ErrManag:

    If Err.Description <> "" Then
        MsgBox Err.Description 'This will prompt the error if a char is inserted
    End If

End Sub
```

In this example the user will have the opportunity to correct it, but if he doesn't you have to recheck it later when clicking the "Send" button like Hrqls suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub txtName_Validate(Cancel As Boolean)
   If txtName.Text = "" Then
      MsgBox "Please enter your name!", vbExclamation, ""
      Cancel = True
   End If
End Sub
```

When the Cancel parameter is `True`, the input focus goes back to the `txtName` control.

```
Private Sub txtPhone_Validate(Cancel As Boolean)
   If Len(txtPhone.Text) < 10 Then
      MsgBox "Enter the phone number in 10 digits!", vbExclamation, ""
      Cancel = True
   End If
End Sub
```

In this case, the input focus moves back to the `txtPhone` control when the Cancel parameter is set to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

you can enter the statements in the validation event of a text box control.
while entering in the box it automatically validates the data in the text box so it can be identified the data inserted